# in onPurchasesUpdated, how to get accountid which was setted in BillingFlowParams

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1 for android's in app billing. I start pay in below code:

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                            .setSku(productId)
                            .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                            .setAccountId(accountId)
                            .build();
billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams);
```

It will callback on:

```
void onPurchasesUpdated(@BillingResponse int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases);
```

The question is how to get account which was seated in BillingFlowParams?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer or solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

**We recommend that you use a one-way hash to generate a
string from the user's ID and store the hashed string in this field as mentioned in documentation**:

```
/**
 * Specify an optional obfuscated string that is uniquely associated with the user's account in
 * your app.
 *
 * <p>If you pass this value, Google Play can use it to detect irregular activity, such as many
 * devices making purchases on the same account in a short period of time. Do not use the
 * developer ID or the user's Google ID for this field. In addition, this field should not
 * contain the user's ID in cleartext. **We recommend that you use a one-way hash to generate a
 * string from the user's ID and store the hashed string in this field**.
 *
 * <p>Optional:
 *
 * <ul>
 *   <li>To buy in-app item
 *   <li>To create a new subscription
 *   <li>To replace an old subscription
 * </ul>
 */
public Builder setAccountId(String accountId) {
  this.mAccountId = accountId;
  return this;
}
```

> Optional obfuscated string that is uniquely associated with the user's account in your app. If you pass this value, Google Play can use it to detect irregular activity, such as many devices making purchases on the same account in a short period of time

Answer (score 0):

First we have to override the `onPurchasesUpdated()` to handle response codes.

```
@Override
void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK
            && purchases != null) {
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            handlePurchase(purchase);
        }
    } else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user cancelling the purchase flow.
    } else {
        // Handle any other error codes.
    }
}
```

Then we have to get the purchase token to acknowledge any transactions that was correctly held to get the accounts that is needed only if the `billingResult.getResponseCode()` is and `BillingResponse.OK`.

```
BillingClient client = ...
AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = ...

void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    if (purchase.getState() == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        // Grant entitlement to the user.
        ...

        // Acknowledge the purchase if it hasn't already been acknowledged.
        if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {
            AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams =
                AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder()
                    .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                    .build();
            client.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Then only one thing remains:

```
void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {
    if (purchase.getState() == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
        // Acknowledge purchase and grant the item to the user
    } else if (purchase.getState() == PurchaseState.PENDING) {
        // Here you can confirm to the user that they've started the pending
    }
}
```

Here the `class Purchase` has numerous `public methods` like `getOrderId()` and `getOriginalJson()` to get the details of the account which was seated on billing.
[More details](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase#isAcknowledged).